# Are service objects necessary in OOP?

Tags: object-oriented, architecture, object-oriented-design, encapsulation, separation-of-concerns

I have been using AngularJs since a long time. Me and my team makes heavy use of services for retrieving the remote resources like `Users` which intern uses `$http` service so, basically, for each entity, I have services which fetches/stores etc that entity.

I was thinking why not the entity itself should be able to do that and services should be totally removed. I don't know if I am going in that direction but I need to know the opinion of others.

Comment: BTW, is Repository a kind of Service?

Comment: `I was thinking why not the entity itself should be able to do that`. It's named Active Record design pattern. It's considered anti-pattern by several reasons.

Comment: How about doing one service per backend rather than one service per class/resource? That way you're not overdoing it, while still ensuring that you're never left with invalid objects (e.g. creating a user with a user ID that doesn't exist).

Comment: @Laiv: if you're going to declare an antipattern, be prepared to explain your reasons.  Simply stating that something is bad without explaining why is pointless and unproductive.

Comment: Well, the intention was to give a few hints about the subject and let the OP to do a little research. There's a lot of literature about the subject. I considered that I could not say anything relevant about the pattern that had not already been said before. If the pattern is good or not, IMO is something we have to figure out by ourselfs. The same happens with anti-patterns, you can come to your own conclusions or just belive what others says.

Comment: @Laiv that can be said about almost all the answers given on SE.

Comment: @CodiYogi some questions are harder than others. This one has been argued countless time. I'm afraid two things: end up repeating what others said much better than me and stating an opinionated answer about why you should not use Recative Pattern. However, It would be hypocrital of me ta say so because I have implemented intentionally anti-patterns that, despite what other says, they did the job as expected.

Comment: Just a question. `I don't know if I am going in that direction but I need to know the opinion of others` Why is so important what others opine?

Comment: @Laiv by others I don't mean some fruit seller but someone more experienced in the required domain and hence why I am here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extensive use of "service" is indicative of bad OOP. However, the nature of development sometimes make service-like classes unavoidable, such as in your case.

Your user entity should not be responsible for storing or retrieving itself; storing itself does not violate OOP, however, it violates many good architectural practices such as separation of concerns and the single responsibility principal. Allowing an object to store and retrieve it self will make your application *very* brittle, and hard to maintain.

You will need storage and retrieval service; however, simply labeling it a service is somewhat lazy imo. OOP is about nouns that verb; let's make this service a little more OOP...

An object that is responsible for only CRUD is called a repository. It should *not* contain anything other than CRUD methods.  If you find your repository having a method like *GiveUserPermission* you are violating the repository pattern, it does not belong there; it either belongs in the User class or a mediator class of User and Permission. Each entity should have its own repository. A repository should not be responsible for multiple entities. And remember, it is per entity, not per table.

It is irrelevant whether your repository gets its data from a database or a http rest call; the rest of your application should be ignorant to this detail.

Comment: So, If I need to get all images of an user, then which repository is responsible for it? `users` or `images`?

Comment: @CodeYogi It depends, I need more info on what you are making. But it does not belong in the user repository. You need to think about what kind of image it is and what it represents in your application.

Comment: Ok, lets say I have hotel and a hotel can have many images like we see on booking.com

Comment: In this case, you would have HotelImageRepository which returns to you a list of HotelImages objects associated with a particular hotel. You would then use the keys of those objects to retrieve the actual image data as needed from an image loader.

Comment: In your example above `GiveUserPermission` is a method that needs to interact with database table or tables and by your definition there needs to be a repository in that case what should I name it?

Comment: @CodeYogi Incorrect. You should have a UsersPermissions Object, or something similar, then you pass it to the Save/Update method of the UserPermissionsRepository

Comment: What would be there in `HotelImages` objects?

Answer (score 0):

In DDD entities do not load themselves from the repository, that's the responsibility of an Application service. It is done this way in order to keep the entities pure, with no side effects. In this way you gain at least two advantages: 1) they are more testable and 2) the command operations are retry-able (this combined with optimistic locking is a big step for scalability).

However, the front-end is not a classic candidate for the Aggregate tactical design pattern (if you use AngularJs as a client application as opposed to a nodejs back-end application). So you probably enforce the business rules in the server side of your application, for security reasons. This means that your front-end just sends commands to the back-end application where you have an Aggregate that in turn change state according to the business rules and it does not have business rules that must be enforced. In best case, you have some business rules duplicated for a better UX.

In conclusion, in the front-end you don't have DDD entites/aggregates so you can use any loading pattern you want.

Comment: Not all OOP is DDD

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer of course, but the context is DDD (see the question's tags)

Comment: My apologies, I did not notice

Comment: Despite the tags, the question has nothing to do with DDD

Comment: @Laiv then remove that tag

Comment: `In conclusion, in the front-end you don't have DDD entites/aggregates so you can use any loading pattern you want.` This's is debatable. AngularJS apps are not mere dumb front-ends. They are meant to be applications per se, otherwise, we would not speak about AngularJs as a framework. So, why they should not approach its implementation from a DDD point of view?

Comment: @Laiv you could but you'd duplicate the logic from the backend

Comment: So basically, any client-side app is a dump app with no logic and business than retrieving and show data? Or at least looks like client-side applications don't deserve different approaches than MVx design patterns. Very, very debatable

Comment: @Laiv it's not like that. It really depends. Client app have some kind of logic but in the end the backend is the final validator for the business rules.